# Convert to int with data style NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

After upgrading from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2017 a stored procedure feeding a quarterly report is failing to provide information. Identified the issue as the procedure is failing to generate a variable that drives the rest of the procedure.

Identified the variable wasn't being set due to a CONVERT statement using the data style NULL. If the query below is run on SQL Server 2017 the variable @CountFrequency returns NULL, as expected based on the Microsoft Doc regarding CONVERT and data style NULL. If that query is run on SQL Server 2012 or 2016 @CountFrequency returns 4, which allowed the stored procedure to run successfully in our production environment prior to the upgrade.

```sql
DECLARE @OwnerCountUDF varchar(30) = '4'
    , @CountFrequency int
;

IF ISNUMERIC(@OwnerCountUDF) = 1
    SELECT @CountFrequency = CONVERT(int,@OwnerCountUDF,NULL)
ELSE 
    SELECT @CountFrequency = 1
;

SELECT ISNUMERIC(@OwnerCountUDF) 'Numeric'
    , @OwnerCountUDF '@OwnerCountUDF'
    , @CountFrequency '@CountFrequency'
;
```

Have been unable to find any documentation about a change to CONVERT which would cause this difference in results.

Comment: Care to `ISNUMERIC()` as it produce wrong results.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's what Books Online for SQL Server 2005 says: "When *style* is `NULL`, the result returned is also `NULL`." This means that this behavior, if it was present in older versions, was always a bug in that it does not agree with even the oldest version of the documentation, although if the behavior changed without a change in the database compatibility level, that is in itself an undocumented breaking change.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which is annotated *SQL Server (starting with 2008)*:

> **style**
>
> An integer expression that specifies how the CONVERT function will translate expression. For a style value of NULL, NULL is returned. data_type determines the range.

Perhaps your compatibility level was set to an even earlier version in the SQL Server 2012 version.

Comment: The compatibility level for our test environment running SQL Server 2016 is 110 and when running the query there @CountFrequency returns 4

Comment: @IThompson . . . Your use of the `NULL` third argument directly contradicts the documentation.  I think you should approach this as a bug and fix the code -- probably in both systems.

Comment: I did end up removing the NULL from the CONVERT statement to have our report being able to run again. Currently am unable to get an answer as to why the statement was written that way originally and still wondering as to why the difference in results between the SQL Server instances.